# Flutter navState context

Tags: flutter

I searched for a way to navigate through notification and i had to find solution for using context out of widget scoped so i created Global variable and Navigator state and used it, it worked fine.
Now i'm thinking why i have to pass every route push the context of the widget, why not use the navigator state on every route push.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Global variables
/// * [GlobalKey<NavigatorState>]
class GlobalVariable {
  /// This global key is used in material app for navigation through firebase notifications.
  /// [navState] usage can be found in [notification_notifier.dart] file.
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navState = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

adding to the MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
        title: 'myapp',
        navigatorKey: GlobalVariable.navState,



Navigator.push(GlobalVariable.navState.currentContext, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RoutePage(child: ContactForm())));
```

instead of

```
(context) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RoutePage(child: ContactForm())));
```